# Is there any restriction for including number of html tables for IE6?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6

Anybody knows how many tables we can include in html to render properly with css style in IE6?

Currently in one of html page, there are around 56 tables. For few tables there is css and others are just for layout purpose. But if i include one more table with css, i.e 57th, style is not rendered at all for that table.

what may be the reason?

Comment: I'm fairly sure there is no limitation for this low a number. Can you show some code?

Comment: Thanks all for your answers. the problem was not related to tables. It was related to css, where service was including same css file for each iteration of the html table(ie. 56 times in single html). I just removed it and included once, n it seems working fine for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a limit for any HTML markup inclusion.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget that the rendering occurs on the client - so for some people it will die at a lower number of tables, eg if they have low RAM available.

Comment: I'm sorry but this answer doesn't make any sense. Are you suggesting 57 tables  are too many for the average computer?